# Passing value to ajaxform data

Tags: jquery

I want to pass the value of the variable to ajaxForm data.

```
value1 = "dynamic_value1";
value2 = "dynamic_value2";
$('form').ajaxForm({
    data: {
      key1: value1, 
      key2: value2 
    }
});
```

Expecting something like:

```
date:{Key1:"dynamic_value1", Key2:"dynamic_value2"}
```

So in php i can access like

```
echo $_POST['key1'];
```

======================
COMPLETE script

```
<script src="../../bin/addons/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="../../bin/addons/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>
// jQuery Form-plugin 
(function() {
  var value1 = "dynamic_value1";
  var value2 = "dynamic_value2";
  $('.dummyForm1').ajaxForm({
    data:{
      key1: value1,
      key2: value2
  }
  complete: function(xhr) {
      txt = xhr.responseText;
      alert(txt);
  }
}); 
})(); 
</script>

<form class="dummyForm1" action="form-php.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Hit!" />
</form>
```

form-php.php

```
<?
  echo "Key1 value:". $_POST['key1'];
?>
```

Comment: So you just want to InitCase the Key names?

Comment: I need a value of variable to be passed in JSON during AjaxForm call?

Comment: The code you have now should work fine. What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: could not get the values using: echo $_POST['key1']; in php

Comment: @Chandu: Please refer my post now, i added the complete script...

Comment: I think you were missing a comma after data property of options. Check the answer posted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing a comma after the data property.

Try this:

```
(function () {
    var value1 = "dynamic_value1";
    var value2 = "dynamic_value2";
    $('.dummyForm1').ajaxForm({
        data: {
            key1: value1,
            key2: value2
        }, //You were missing this comma.
        complete: function (xhr) {
            txt = xhr.responseText;
            alert(txt);
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Adding that missing comma fixed that issue

Comment: Can I pass a blob file to  upload data this way?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the given solution is that the ajaxform will fill the variables when the event handler is called.

```
var value1 = "dynamic_value1";
/*This will be sent*/
var value2 = "dynamic_value2";
(function () {
    $('.dummyForm1').ajaxForm({
        data: {
            /*On load of event handler the values are set, they are not dynamic anymore*/
            key1: value1,
            key2: value2
        },
        complete: function (xhr) {
            txt = xhr.responseText;
            alert(txt);
        }
    });
})();
/*This will not be sent*/
value2 = "new value";
```

You may use a function to return the current state of global variables

```
var value1 = "dynamic_value1";
/*This will not be sent*/
var value2 = "dynamic_value2";
(function () {
    $('.dummyForm1').ajaxForm({
        data: {
            /*On load of event handler the values are set, they are not dynamic anymore*/
            key1: value1,
            key2: function () {
                /*this returns the current state of the global variable*/
                return value2;
            }
        },
        complete: function (xhr) {
            txt = xhr.responseText;
            alert(txt);
        }
    });
})();
/*This will be sent*/
value2 = "new value";
```